Numbers above marital status on ship's manifest
I found a copy of the ship's manifest record from when my great-grandfather came over from Italy. His name is Giovanni DiDomenico. To my surprise, he was listed as a widower, which I was not aware of. However, above his marital status a number 2 is written. Any idea what this could mean? 

It's not a 2 written above the marital status, but the beginning of a long string of numbers and dashes written above the line: 2-752134-7-30-40.
Was your great-grandfather by any chance naturalized in 1940?

This is spot-on. There has been some action taken to verify the passenger's arrival, and the 7-30-40 string is the date associated with the action.  See Marian L. Smith's article on Manifest Markings at JewishGen for other examples, in the subsection "Markings on the Manifest's Occupation Column".
